# How to write less in "new"

Tags: javascript

Construction like "this.uuid = uuid..." and etc seems ugly. How can I write it better?

Seems like this is not the best way.

```js
function account({
  uuid,
  email,
  pass,
  device_id,
  max_rep = 10,
  max_like = 10,
  max_comm = 10,
  max_sub = 10
}) {
  this.uuid = uuid;
  this.email = email;
  this.pass = pass;
  this.device_id = device_id;
  this.max_rep = max_rep;
  this.max_like = max_like;
  this.max_com = max_comm;
  this.max_sub = max_sub;
}

a = new account({
  uuid: '12',
  email: "g@mail.ru",
  pass: "123",
  device_id: "444"
})

b = new account({
  uuid: '13',
  email: "ab@mail.ru",
  pass: "456",
  device_id: "777"
})

console.log(a,b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure the props, then generate an object from the props, and assign it to `this`:

```js
function account({
  uuid,
  email,
  pass,
  device_id,
  max_rep = 10,
  max_like = 10,
  max_comm = 10,
  max_sub = 10
}) {
  Object.assign(this, {
    uuid,
    email,
    pass,
    device_id,
    max_rep,
    max_like,
    max_comm,
    max_sub
  });
}

const a = new account({
  uuid: '12',
  email: "g@mail.ru",
  pass: "123",
  device_id: "444"
})

const b = new account({
  uuid: '13',
  email: "ab@mail.ru",
  pass: "456",
  device_id: "777"
})

console.log(a)

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object in the function, then assign its properties and return:

```js
function account(obj) {
  const act = {};
  
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)){
     act[key] = value;
  }
  ["max_rep", "max_like", "max_comm", "max_sub"].forEach((prop) => {
    act[prop] = obj[prop] ? obj[prop] : 10;
  })

  return act;
}

const a = account({
  uuid: '12',
  email: "g@mail.ru",
  pass: "123",
  device_id: "444",
  max_rep: "123"
})

const b = account({
  uuid: '13',
  email: "ab@mail.ru",
  pass: "456",
  device_id: "777"
})

console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: beware of that one: if obj comes from an api response for instance, obj can contain the property hasOwnProperty (say value is a string) and will fail upon instantiation (since you think of calling the method but actually get the maliciously setted value..)

Comment: I think you (as me) also misread the title. op does not want to write less new but less assignment in constructor (he probably forgot to write Account instead of account)

Comment: @grodzi I interpreted his question as wanting a DRYer function, I think my answer provides that, especially by bypassing the object literal being passed in as a parameter.

Comment: I agree with you. I just highlight that bypassing "this" and the instantiation may be not what op asks